# Dealing with Google spidering JavaScript incorrectly

Tags: google, web-crawlers, googlebot

Google spiders JavaScript now to look for possible URLs.  This is mostly a good thing, but occasionally it gets it wrong.  Is there any way to hide possible URLs in JavaScript from googlebot?

For example, I have some code like this:

```js
var url = "/some/object/--ct_id--/".replace('--ct_id--', content_id);
```

Regular users end up going to the correct URLs because the `--ct_id--` is replaced with an integer.  Google seems to be trying to spider "/some/object/--ct_id--/" which isn't a valid link.

Does anyone know what triggers the URL detection?  Should I change the variable name?  Should I escape the slashes with unicode notation?

Comment: Just because Google tries to crawl it, there isn't a problem.   It doesn't count against your site in any way.   It just makes the report in Google Search Console noisy.

Comment: We get asked about 404 errors in search console a lot here.   I'm not sure that these questions have the exact same issues, but the answers are helpful: [Is it possible for a script tag to be perceived as an inbound link for SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72221/is-it-possible-for-a-script-tag-to-be-perceived-as-an-inbound-link-for-seo) and [Google follows JavaScript string as relative path - produces 404 error](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50848/google-follows-javascript-string-as-relative-path-produces-404-error)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Well in the example given, the backend is expecting an integer but gets "--ct_id--" instead and throws an error and I get an email about it.  So, it's generating other noise I'd like to cut back on too.

Comment: The heuristic that Googlebot uses is triggering based on the slashes in the string literal.   `"|some|object|--ct_id--|".replace('|','/').replace('--ct_id--', content_id)`  would probably do better.   However, now that Google knows about that "URL" it may continue to crawl it periodically even if the page doesn't link to it.   You may just have to configure your server not to send out email for that case.

Comment: I have my server configured to email me about 404 errors only when the referrer is from my own site .  This allows me to catch broken internal links but doesn't get very noisy from crawler errors.  Crawlers almost never send referrers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - my other issue is 401 errors.  I have javascript that makes calls only when the user is signed in, but Google tries hitting those URLs otherwise and triggering several 401 errors in reports.  They're ajax calls and that's why they don't just redirect to a login page.

Comment: The 401 status should only be used with HTTP authentication schemes like "Basic Authentication" and "Digest Authentication".   The [RFC states](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) that "The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource."     I usually use a `200 OK` status with AJAX like `{error: "not logged in"}` in those cases.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - this is getting a little off topic..  I am following the RFC and including the header.  I use the status code to trigger a redirect of the UI to the login screen.  I did it that way so it's handled in my `fail` methods instead of my `success` methods (since it was a failure) and a generic `fail` handler can always redirect the user to the login.